# Is using Chrome and Tor Browser at the same time secure?

Tags: linux, tor, chrome

I question this recently because as I was using the Tor Browser, while in the same time my Google-Chrome was opened, and I right-clicked on a word to search it in 'Disconect', when the page loaded I get message from the AntiScript plugin which really freaked me out:

> NoScript filtered a potential cross-site scripting (XSS) attempt from
>   [:chrome]. Technical details have been logged to the Console.

I'm using OpenSuse Tumbleweed (latest version) and I have no firewall, proxy, or VPN stuff.

Comment: Tor Browser is based on Firefox. Firefox refers to its UI as *chrome*, so the error is almost certainly unrelated to Google-Chrome.

Comment: Avoid Google. Install Ghostery. Avoid Chrome. It is horrible for privacy. Disable phishing and malware protection in Firefox because it sends domains to Google.

Comment: Ghostery kind of defeats the purpose of not being tracked... they track You when you use there services. The Phishing and Malware protection does send domains... but so does all your packets and all your DNS requests. (not really more data leaked that way) I suggest you educate yourself further before you tell people to use X product.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a bug in Tor Browser, as stated here:

> bug report:
>   https://www.mail-archive.com/tor-bugs@lists.torproject.org/msg78499.html
>   answer:
>   https://www.mail-archive.com/tor-bugs@lists.torproject.org/msg81303.html

Check the answer, there is a possible fix.

Regarding your question, that error message always shows "Chrome", it shouldn't be able to see other browser's data.

By the way, pressing ctrl-shift-j opens up the console, where you can check additional information about NoScript.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is the interface of all browsers and tor browser is simply referring to it's interface(firefox). Google Chrome has a chrome(interface) too it is fairly confusing. Disconnect is not a white listed site in NoScript.